# Vartiational / Energy Formulation vs Weak formulation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$ be a classical solution to
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = f,& x \in U\\
u=g,& x \in \partial U
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then this is equivalent to saying that $u$ is the minimiser of the energy functional
\begin{align*}
I[w]:=\int_U (\frac{1}{2} |\nabla w|^2 - wf) dx
\end{align*}
over the class of functions $\mathcal{A}:=\{u\mid u=g \text{ on } \partial U\}$. My question is, how is the 'weak' formulation of a PDE different from the energy formulation? To illustrate my question:

$u \in W^{1,2}(U)$ solves the Poisson equation weakly if and only if $u-g \in W_0^{1,2}(U)$ and (forget that we already know about the regularity of the solution)
\begin{align*}
\int_U -\Delta u v-fv &= 0, \text{ for all }v \in C^{\infty}_c(U)
\end{align*}
We can rewrite using integration by parts + Green's theorem
\begin{align*}
B[u,v]-\langle f,v \rangle:=\int_U \nabla u \cdot \nabla v-fv &= 0\
\end{align*}

Take $u=v$ then $\frac{1}{2}B[u,u] - \langle f,u \rangle = I[u]$. Is such a relationship between the weak formulation and energy formulation a superficial one? What can we say about the relationship between the two methods? $B[u,u]$ is important when showing coercivity in order to apply Lax-Milgram, but this relationship seems to tell us that we need to only know about $B[u,u]$ to derive existence of a weak solution using calculus of variations. This seems to contradict the fact that we need more information about $B[u,v]$ for all test functions $v$ to apply Lax-Milgram in the weak approach. I've read the related questions but they don't seem to address this directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The precise relationship between the energy functional and the terms in the weak formulation is:
$$
I'[u]v = B[u,v]-\langle f,v\rangle,
$$
i.e., the terms in the weak formulation equal the derivative of the energy.
Then the weak formulation is obtained by setting the derivative of the energy functional to zero.

This is only true if $B[u,v]$ is symmetric, i.e., $B[u,v]=B[v,u]$ for all $u,v$. If $B$ is not symmetric then the minimization of $\frac12 B[u,u]-\langle f,u\rangle$ is not equivalent to solving the weak formulation, as the energy ``does not see'' the skew-symmetric part of $B$.

In Lax-Milgram one needs to consider the symmetric part $B[u,u]$ for coercivity, but also the full bilinear form $B[u,v]$ for boundedness.

Comment: By $I^{\prime}[u]v$ do you mean the derivative of $I$ with respect to $u$, and then multiplied by $v$?

Comment: Yes, or equivalently, the directional derivative at $u$ in direction $v$.

Comment: Ah, so you mean $\lim_{\tau \rightarrow 0} \frac{d}{d\tau} I[u+\tau v]$?